# Is there a passive form of "let him sleep"?

Tags: grammar, imperatives

Is it possible to use passive voice without an object? If so, how would it be phrased?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you're trying to say, please?

Comment: He sleeps -- He is slept  -- Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I think he is going for something like: "He was let to sleep." (if that even makes sense)

Comment: There must be an object in the original clause in order to make a passive clause out of it; the resulting passive clause has no object (i.e, it's intransitive), and the subject is different, being the old object. _Let him sleep_ has no passive; it is an order, an imperative. Imperatives don't have passives. In addition, there are two clauses (because there are two main verbs -- _let_ and _sleep_), and passive can only apply to one clause, not to a complex sentence with several clauses.

Comment: let me do the work(active)
let the work be done by me(passive)
there r two verb and it is possible making a passive like the example.I actually want to know that is it possible making passive without object?help me.

Comment: Yoda would say, "Eight hours was slept by him."

Answer (score 1):

***He is allowed to sleep.***

[Or *he is let sleep*, but that is a bit archaic.  I add it pretty much just to have an answer long enough to satisfy SE.  It wouldn't be quite so odd/archaic in the past tense: *He was let sleep.* ;-)]

Comment: Does "he is let to sleep" make sense? It's a guess.

Comment: is it possible making a passive voice without a object?

Comment: In your sentence "him" is the direct object.